# Var does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing "PlayerMoveKeyBoard" with Unity, i used this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
        double speed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        speed = speed * 0.95;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Up")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Down")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (-speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Right")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (0, 0, speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Left")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (0, 0, -speed);
        }
    }
}
```

but it says:

> (17, 11) The name 'speed' does not exist in the current context

Comment: from the code given its right - you havent declared speed - the variables only exist in "start" and then die

Comment: wait.... it needs to be float, not double

Comment: whether `float` or `double` does not make a difference for this kind of error

Comment: [Variable scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx), one of the earlier lesson when learning how to code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have declared the variables locally in the scope of the method `Start`:

```
void Start () {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double speed;
}
```

outside of this method those variable cannot be accessed. You need to declare them on the class level:

```
public class MovingScript : MonoBehaviour {

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double speed;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        speed = speed * 0.95;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Up")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Down")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (-speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Right")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (0, 0, speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Left")) {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate (0, 0, -speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Please read up on [Variables and Method Scope in this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

all the variable that you declare inside a method called local variable and can be accessed only within that method. Here speed is not declared in Update method so you can not access it.It is declared in Start method as soon as you came out of scope of Start method it goes away . In order to access it in Update method you need to declare it in Update method.

Like this:

```
 void Update()
    {
        float speed = 0.0f;
        speed = speed * 0.95;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Up"))
        {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Down"))
        {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate(-speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Right"))
        {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate(0, 0, speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Left"))
        {
            speed += 2;
            transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I will try it i hope it's worked

Comment: no it didn't work because transform.Translate() needed float, not double (maybe i will replace double by float and add "f"

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare speed outside of start, in the class itself.

```
    public class MovingScript : MonoBehaviour {

    double speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;

    }
```